How to count specific values between other values
I'm having a hard time figuring this one out.
I have a short list of numbers in column C (C4 to C19).
Those numbers can range from 0 to anything. Never empty.
In column D is a date, in column E is an offset, but this is not relevant to the problem.
I would like in column F, the count of the value zero, before that line, until we find a non-zero value above that.
So, let's say F18.  I want to know the count of zeroes in C before C18.  The answer is 3.
For F17, the answer is 2 (C16 and C15).
And so on.

I did try to figure it out with some COUNTIFS and INDEX.... but I'm lost.

Show what formula you have tried and the expected output how you want to show the count, btw have you tried using SCAN() here?

Hello, I didn't post the formulas because to be honest, I'm not sure where I was trying to go with it.  I did not try the SCAN formula.  One thing worth noting, is that my excel is in French, so I also have to translate formulas, making it even harder for me.

Translation site I used this one,  has most functions (I've used the dutch version, hope it helps).

It appears that @Lajos Arpad gave the only correct answer because it doesn't include the current row when counting zeroes.

@TomSharpe you are absolutely right.  But I realized afterwards that for my application I prefer using the current row because it is some sort of projection for the current day.  I didn't think about that at first I guess.

This one does it the other way around (top to bottom):
=IFERROR(SCAN(0,C4:C19,LAMBDA(a,v,IF(v=0,a+1,0))),"")

I hope I'm not breaking any rules, but here is it in French:
=SIERREUR(SCAN(0;C4:C19;LAMBDA(a;v;SI(v=0;a+1;0)));"")


WOW, thanks a lot.  I reversed my table, it doesn't matter which way it is, and this is working just fine!! Only had to translate it.

@JessySaint added translation, but not sure if it's accurate though. Luckily it's only 3 functions.

My French and working version :
=SIERREUR(SCAN(0;C4:C19;LAMBDA(a;v;SI(v=0;a+1;0)));"")

Here is one way doing it using SCAN() as mentioned in comments:


=SCAN(0,C4:C19=0,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y,x+1,0)))


Revised Formula: Edit -- 4/17/2024 --> Credit to Tom Sharpe Sir and Lajos Arpad Sir, for highlighting the actual logic.
=DROP(VSTACK(0,SCAN(0,C4:C19=0,LAMBDA(x,y,y*(x+1)))),-1)



Here is @Lajos Arpad's solution as a lambda (with apologies):
=LET(data,C4:C19,SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),
LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c=1,0,LET(prev,INDEX(data,c-1),a*(prev=0)+(prev=0))))))


Or slightly shorter
=LET(data,C4:C19,SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),
LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c=1,0,LET(prev,INDEX(data,c-1),(a+1)*(prev=0))))))


Bonus: can you do it without a lambda? Yes, e.g. find the difference between the number of the previous row and the number of the last row before the current one that has a non-zero in it:
=LET(data,C4:C19,s,SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),fs,FILTER(s,data<>0),s-XLOOKUP(s-1,fs,fs,0,-1,-1)-1)


Tom Sir, appreciate your findings. It has always helped to learn. May I ask ? Will this not work as per the logic stated --> =DROP(VSTACK(0,SCAN(0,C4:C19=0,LAMBDA(x,y,y*(x+1)))),-1)

Yes that's perfect and much shorter.

My understanding is that in the F column's i'th cell we need the length of 0-segments in C up to, but not including the i'th column, up to the first cell in C which is either not 0 or out of range. If my understanding is correct, then this is the expected result:

and you can achieve this via
=($C4=0) * $F4 + ($C4=0)

in $F5.
Explanation:

$C4=0 evaluates to boolean and is converted to numeric when multiplied with something, that is, after the conversion, it will be 0 if it was false and 1 if it was true
$F4 is the sum so far, we multiply it with 1 if we had a zero in the previous row and 0 if we had a 1
we add 1 if the row above has a 0 and 0 if the row above has a 1


Just XMATCHing for fun :)
=LAMBDA(_r,
LET(
_next_largest, 0.1,
_comment, CONCAT("Count of values below '", _next_largest, "' in the rows above"),
_above, LAMBDA(_row_index,  INDEX(_r,1,1):INDEX(_r,_row_index-1,1)),
_indices, SEQUENCE(ROWS(_r)),
_offset_to_matched, LAMBDA(_row_index,_matched, _row_index - 1 - _matched),

MAP(_indices, LAMBDA(i,
IF(i = 1, _comment,
IFNA(_offset_to_matched(i, XMATCH(_next_largest, _above(i),1,-1)), "")
)))))(_r)



Or with SCAN,OFFSET and XMATCH:
=LAMBDA(arr, LET(
_next_largest, 0.1,
_comment, CONCAT("Count of values below '", _next_largest, "' in the rows above"),
SCAN(1,SEQUENCE(ROWS(_r)), LAMBDA(a,_row_index,
IF(_row_index = 1, _comment,
IFNA(_row_index - 1 - XMATCH(0.1,OFFSET(_r,0,0,_row_index-1),1,-1), "")
)))))(_r)

